# Make same #define in every file

Tags: c, preprocessor

I want to make a script that add a file ID number at every .C and .H file. This is used to identity from which file a error message is generated.

So every file has a unique number like:

```
fileID        (magic)
```

The problem is this only needs to exits in that file. Because every file have it's own.

edit: I need a number and not a string. So `__FILE__` doesn't work.

Comment: You can simply use the file’s path via the implicitly defined `__FILE__` macro.

Comment: With macro magic, code could hash `__FILE__` into a certainly unique 64-bit number.

Comment: Why do you need number for header files? Headers shouldn't have any function definitions, so no functions which could generate error messages. And even if you would have function defintions in headers, wouldn't it be better to use the ID of the source file where header is included in, because header can be included in multiple source files?

Answer (score 6):

I generally use this macro for my error messages:

```
#define P_ERR(format, ...) \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d:%s: " format "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, strerror(errno), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

You can read about all such macros in the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

Specific for `__FILE__`:

> `__FILE__`
>   This macro expands to the name of the current input file, in the form of a C string constant. This is the path by which the preprocessor opened the file, not the short name specified in ‘#include’ or as the input file name argument. For example, "/usr/local/include/myheader.h" is a possible expansion of this macro.

Comment: There’s no need to flush `stderr`, it’s not buffered. And once that’s dropped, the `do…while` guard is also unnecessary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, yes the `linux` manual does mention that but I use `macOS`. Unfortunately, most SO posts say "typically" for the same and I couldn't find any docs specifying that for posix or mac. If you have link to any, kindly share it with me.

Comment: [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html), [macOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/setbuf.3.html) (technically iOS, but the internals are the same, the links to the man pages for macOS just all 404). The wording “typically” is overly defensive and not technically correct: it’s *always* unbuffered *by default*. You  application can *change* this behaviour, but unless it does, stderr is unbuffered.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, well that's cool. My macOS manual(`man stderr`) doesn't mention that but it always follows POSIX anyways, so that's great. Pretty cool, that would reduce some unecessary code.

Comment: C17 standard draft (also found in C89) §7.21.3 p7 says *"... As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; ..."*. That means it's either *unbuffered* or *line buffered*. Since you your format string ends with `\n`, there should not be need for explicit flushing.

Comment: I need a number and not a string. It for a embedded system so I don't have a terminal.

Comment: @user3202429, I would need a better understanding about your problem If I were to give a good suggestion. What comes to my mind first is to hash the string value into a number (like by using murmur hash and handling collisinons) but that sounds a little stupid at the same time. Maybe you can have a key-val file containing file->fileid mapping which you can parse whenever needed. If any of these sound suitable to you, I will update my answer. I haven't dealt much with embedded systems so not very good at this.

Comment: Not everybody is a windows programmer you now. The value needs to be transferred by canbus to the host system. Strings take a lot of space I don't have. So a hash of ```__FILE__````  is perfect. Only It takes minutes to compiler. So It is not very useable. I was hoping for an answer and not explaining why.